# Contract.on event not working when creating the provider and signer in an async function

Tags: ethers.js

many thanks for reviewing this question. Im currently developing a wordpress based Dapp and I am having trouble.

Firstly, i connect to the users wallet using the following:

```
    walletconnect: {
      package: WalletConnectProvider.default, // required
      options: {
        rpc: {
          4: "INFURA",
        },
        
       
      }
    }
  };
  
  const web3Modal = new Web3Modal.default({
    cacheProvider: false, // optional
    providerOptions // required
  });

  async function getWallet(){
  
    web3Modal.clearCachedProvider();
    instance = await web3Modal.connect();
    provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(instance);
    signer = provider.getSigner();
    contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

  }
```

This is fine, it connects and allows interaction with the contract using ethers.js

Then further along in my code i wish to declare some listeners for contract events using .on, for example,

```
contract.on("winnerFound", (level, winner, prize, index) => {
//do something
}
```

I get the following error,

Uncaught TypeError: contract is undefined

Now it seems to me, because when the page is loading, it loads in the javascript with the contract.on, but at the point of page loading, contract is not defined yet as we need to wait for the user to give us a signer.

Is there a way to get around this? Getting the provider requires asynchronous function so Im out of ideas!

Comment: Can you ensure to use await? Seems like the promise is not being resolve by that step